# React Native - Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: meteor, react-native

I try to subscribe from `react-native` to `meteor` by using `ddp` driver. During the `componentDidMount`, it gives me the exception

`Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op.`

This is my code

```
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
                rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => !_.isEqual(row1, row2),
            }),
            loaded: false,
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log('component mounted');
        console.log(this.props['actor']);

        ddp.initializeWithSubscribe(() => {
            ddp.subscribe('select-all-meals-by-restaurant', [this.props['actor']['obj']['_id']]);
        });

        var ddpClient = ddp.connection;
        var observer = ddpClient.observe('meals');

        observer.added = () => this.updateRows(_.cloneDeep(_.values(ddpClient.collections.meals)));
        observer.changed = () => this.updateRows(_.cloneDeep(_.values(ddpClient.collections.meals)));
        observer.removed = () => this.updateRows(_.cloneDeep(_.values(ddpClient.collections.meals)));
    },

    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Util function for watching data
     *-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    updateRows: function(rows) {
        console.log('rows :' + rows);

        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(rows),
            loaded: true,
        });
    },
```

Can you suggest me a way to solve this ?

Comment: Everything seems completely perfect to me :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This explains what's happening and how to fix it:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Basically you are receiving updates after you component has been unmounted. You need to use `componentWillUnmount` to unsubscribe from changes from Meteor.